# Using Parameters<F> infer arguments type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to write a `call` function:

```
function call<F extends (...arg: any) => any, P extends Parameters<F>>(
  fn?: F,
  ...arg: P
): ReturnType<F> | undefined {
  if (fn) return fn(...arg) // Type 'P' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator
}

const fn = (a: string) => {}

// automatically infer `fn` arguments type
call(fn, )
```

what should I do？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in TypeScript; see [microsoft/TypeScript#36874](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36874). It looks like the problem is triggered by `F extends (...arg: any) => any` instead of `F extends (...arg: any[]) => any`.  That is, your `arg` rest parameter is of the anything-at-all `any` type instead of the *array*-of-anything `any[]` type.  The obvious workaround is therefore to change `any` to `any[]`, which shouldn't be a problem because function rest parameters are essentially always arraylike:

```
function call<F extends (...arg: any[]) => any, P extends Parameters<F>>(
  fn?: F, ...arg: P): ReturnType<F> | undefined {
  return fn?.(...arg) // okay (I used optional chaining here to deal with missing fn)
}
```

Looks good!

---

That's the answer to the question as asked, although it is useful to note that generally speaking, the preferred way to do this is to make `call()` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in `P` (the rest parameter type) and `R` (the return type), and not use [the `Parameters<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) and [the `ReturnType<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) utility types:

```
function call<P extends any[], R>(fn?: (...arg: P) => R, ...arg: P): R | undefined {
  return fn?.(...arg); // okay
}
```

They are similar, but your approach ends up being unable to properly represent what happens when `fn` is itself generic:

```
const pair = <T, U>(left: T, right: U): [T, U] => [left, right];

const ret = call(pair, "abc", 123); // old version of call
// const ret: [any, any] | undefined ☹
```

whereas the approach I recommend can take advantage of [the support for higher order type inference from generic functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions):

```
const ret = call(pair, "abc", 123); // new version of call
// const ret: [string, number] | undefined
```

If you can rewrite generics using [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) like `Parameters<T>` and `ReturnType<T>`, it will sometimes improve the compiler's ability to produce desirable results.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBAhgGzQHgGKIKYAeUeYAJgM6IAUAdHSgE4DmAXIimAJ4DaAugJSIAvAD52XADSIACviIkKMxigC2eYg3I4RIqgFgAUIkTAwAfjbYpdGo1Yz+bAErqQDMABVOABzzbEAD6I4KR4wDBgeKSIAN6Gxgyu7ibmNLT0zIIA9FmIcADWKJyGAL6GEAjkUCnC1ChsVQwRTIKisYhlBuWV1d4oMAy1mB5SAKq6aGFQbCOITUwAFtOIo46I3LOjvMJi3JPAUFLzS7wA3N1gVXPqtagYVH0DUgBEKABGEM9SAIwATADM-HOBhyyB612W3A4nCk0O2QRCYQiUUMhjAqjw5D6EDwiAAogA3EgAIXUGli8RM4Gg8CQdywskIxDIlGhfCkTl0pgs1BsdjY0laYic1gy9kFzkCwTISMi0TiRmMELcSG5aT5mVOiFBBSKlM6xgql16-UGQkQwzGEymMyOMEWy1WbA2Y22bT2UztDrOlKNV0S1XN9Ieppe70+PwBQMpoL91QDzsazSkYBAKjeeAY8OloXCctRBhKQA)

Comment:  Your answer is detailed, no doubt I will use the way you recommended, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky one, but the solution is not.

You have to ensure the typescript that args is iterable. You can do that like manually saying to him - `Hey this will be an array, believe me`

[Working playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBAhgGzQHgGKIKYAeUeYAJgM6IAUAdHSgE4DmAXIimAJ4CUiAvAD52XADSIACviIkKExigC2eYg3I4BAqgChEiYGAD8bbCJ2I6NRk3JtxW7mwBKykAzAAVTgAc86xAB9EcFI8YBgwPFJEAG8zGGBqfW5Y3VTEBhc3PTBaOiorShRCrgBtAF1ubjMAX0QzDKhXJGDQ8MiAbi1qrS0IBHIobP5qFDYBhnCmXkEY5H64NDwaNDgmKgADFEQACyLEADd0EDw2ABJolGr17m6tAHo79hAoOAUUWFQMTkRw4DwGRDrfTrdjMEBKMBQShQbx4XroNBUfRiABEKHRKKqvX6g30AGFXl5FgRhlQwIoTohxpMxCgmJSwOCAEb-aZCaJzMDkBZLFZrdbkpRnaKCvC1OmU84Sq43HqfRH4wnE1EAKTg2zAKLEAGYAJzcIA)

```js
function call<F extends (...arg: any) => any, P extends Parameters<F>>(
  fn?: F,
  ...args: P
): ReturnType<F> | undefined {
  if (fn){
      // here is the ugly hint to typescript
      return fn(...(args as any[]))
  } 
  return undefined;
}
```

Comment: Means I have to use type assertion？but shouldn't the type P be an array？

Comment: typescript is not sure P is "spreadable"/ "iterable" evn though for humans it obviously is.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using `apply` as a workaround?

```
function call<F extends (...arg: any) => any, P extends Parameters<F>>(
  fn?: F,
  ...arg: P,
): ReturnType<F> | undefined {
  if (fn) return fn.apply(undefined, arg);

  return undefined;
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/N5zQom)

Comment: Thanks, this is a new solution that I did not expect, I will try it tomorrow